# Handling NULL Parameters in LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say you have parameters(s) in your LINQ query where clause, how do you handle that?

Here is an example:

```
var peoples= from i in individuals
  where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) i.LastName.Equals(lastName))
  select i;
```

Comment: down voter please provide reason for down vote...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to understand what's going on under the hood:

- How query expressions are translated by the compiler
- How LINQ to Objects streams its data, and how it defers execution
- How queries execute remotely via IQueryable and expression trees

It's also worth becoming comfortable with both query expressions, e.g.

```
var query = from person in people
            where person.IsAdult
            select person.Name;
```

and "dot notation":

```
var query = people.Where(person => person.IsAdult)
                  .Select(person => person.Name);
```

Knowing both will let you choose the most readable form for any particular query.

Comment: I have to say the `(person => person.Age >= 18)` temporarily caused my brain to glitch.

Answer (score 10):

The result of a query expression is *a query object*, not *the results of the query*. If you want the results, you can ask the query object to start proffering up results. That is, when you say:

```
var names = from c in customers where c.City == "London" select c.Name;
```

then names is *a query object* that represents "get me the names of all the customers in London". It is *not* a sequence in memory of all the names of customers who live in London; the results of the query are computed on-demand.  It is not until you say:

```
foreach(var name in names) ...
```

that the actual results are computed.

This means that if you ask the same query object for its results twice, the answer might be different. The customers list might have been changed between the first time you ask and the second time you ask. Because queries defer getting their results, you always get fresh results. But you sometimes do the same work twice.

Comment: Thanks. If customers collection changes before you finish enumerating through names, the linq query might return these too, right?

Comment: @Joan: anything can happen in that situation; iterators are not required to give good behaviour when the collection they are referencing changes. Many iterators will throw an exception if that happens.

Answer (score 5):

[101 LinQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) you can start with samples from MSDN

Answer (score 2):

The best advice I could offer someone just starting with `LINQ` is get [`LINQPad`](http://www.linqpad.net/). It is an invaluable tool and will speed up your learning process significantly. And it comes with lots and lots of samples that demonstrate, and let you work with, all the `LINQ` operators.

Comment: LINQPad is a great tool, not only is it great for LINQ, but it is also great for simply checking to see how bit of code works.  It is wonderful for running small code snippets through it since it does not require debugging and you can quickly see how objects are being processed.

Answer (score 2):

You do it in LINQ like you would do in "normal" C#.

In your sample you used string.IsNullOrEmpty(), so you don't differentiate between null and "". If that's the case you could write sth. like the following:

```
if ((lastName ?? "") == (i.LastName ?? ""))
{
   // equal
}
```

Note: [The ?? operator returns the left-hand operand if it is not null, or else it returns the right operand.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173224%28VS.80%29.aspx)

You can integrate that logic into your LINQ query as follows:

```
var peoples = from i in individuals
              where (lastName ?? "") == (i.LastName ?? "")
              select i;
```